# Maui with Blazor page, "There is no content at" message

Tags: c#, blazor, maui

When i run app the main page looks like this:
[Main Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G7J52.png)

In the compiler output there is error like this:
[chromium] [INFO:CONSOLE(2)] "Uncaught ReferenceError: Blazor is not defined", source: https://0.0.0.0/ (2)

I need to add a Blazor page to the existing Maui app. I follow these steps from "Add a BlazorWebView to an existing app": https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/blazorwebview?view=net-maui-7.0 I have never used Blazor, so I can't find how to add root component because in hybrid app there is no app.razor file and builder in MauiProgram.cs has no property "RootComponents". I also created a new project from the template to check if it is something like this there, but I can't find it either. Then I copied wwwroot, Pages, Shared, _imports.razor and MainPage.xaml/.cs from the default project which I created earlier. Then add to MauiProgram.cs these lines:

```
        builder.Services.AddMauiBlazorWebView();
#if DEBUG
        builder.Services.AddBlazorWebViewDeveloperTools();
#endif
```

At the end I modified MainPage.xaml to display Counter.razor:

```
<BlazorWebView HostPage="wwwroot/index.html">
    <BlazorWebView.RootComponents>
        <RootComponent Selector="#app" ComponentType="{x:Type Pages:Counter}"/> 
    </BlazorWebView.RootComponents>
</BlazorWebView>
```

That's how project directories looks like:
[Project Directories](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qS3uY.png)

Properties is the same in my project and sample project.

Comment: Ok, I tested it on new Projects. One on .net 7 and one on .net 8. On .net 7 and mobile this doesn't work but on .net 8 it works fine.

Comment: How can we reproduce this problem? Could you please post the steps of reproducing this problem?

Comment: 1. Create new Project from template: ".NET MAUI Blazor Hybrid App", as Framework choose .NET 7.0

2. Deploy it to android (in my case android 14.0, physical device) 

3. Result: Empty page with "There is no content at" label

Comment: Sorry, I did a test, but I couldn't reproduce this problem.  You can try to update your Visual Studio to the latest version.